# Display date and time like a digital clock in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, datetime

The command `date +'%a %b %e %Y%n%I:%M %p'` displays the date and time in the format:

```
Thu Sep 22 2016
08:02 PM
```

I was trying to think of a way to have the date and time update as the time changes. The only thing I can think of would be to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do 
    date +'%a %b %e %Y%n%I:%M %p'   
done | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

This produces output like:

```
Thu Sep 22 2016
08:02 PM
08:03 PM
08:04 PM
```

Is there a way to display the time change by overwriting the old time so that `08:02` changes to `08:03` on the same line, essentially making the date and time display like a regular digital clock?

Comment: Try preceding your command with `watch -d -n 1`, so use `watch -d -n 1 date +'%a %b %e %Y%n%I:%M %p'`, although that might only show you the time, and you may lose the date part.

Comment: Right now, this is running as fast as it can, even though the value can't possibly change more than once per minute. It's probably not worth the CPU power to be sure you update every few milliseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update the first line only when the day changes, and the second line every second:

```
while :; do
  # store start date in variable
  printf -v start_day '%(%a %b %e %Y)T'
  day=$start_day

  clear
  echo "$day"
  while sleep 1 && [[ $start_day = $day ]]; do
      printf -v day '%(%a %b %e %Y)T'
      printf '\r%(%I:%M %p)T'
  done
done
```

Using `printf %()T` restricts compatibility to recent bash 4.x, but substantially improves performance (avoiding the need to start an external program every time we want to update the time).

Comment: Using the second `printf` option works but is there a way to do this making the date display on the first line and the time display on the next?

Comment: The current version does that -- be sure you have the updated implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tput` to move the cursor around:

```
date +'%a %b %e %Y%n%I:%M %p'
while sleep 1
do
    tput cuu 2
    date +'%a %b %e %Y%n%I:%M %p'
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to have a simple, single-line live digital clock displayed and automatically updated in my `bash(1)` shell when I need it.  Here's the definition of the `clock()` function I implemented, which I use in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```bash
if command -v 'tput' > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        function clock() {
                trap 'tput cnorm; trap - INT ERR' ERR
                trap 'tput cnorm; trap - INT ERR; return' INT
                tput civis
                while :; do
                        echo -e 'cr\nel' | tput -S
                        echo -n "$(date) "
                        sleep 1
                done
        }
fi
```

This function uses the [`tput(1)`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/tput.1.en) utility and the [`terminfo(5)`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/terminfo.5.en) terminal capability database to hide the cursor (`civis` or `cursor_invisible` capability), to move the cursor to the start of the line (`cr` or `carriage_return` capability), and to clear the line to its end (`el` or `clr_eol` capability) before updating its contents.  It also uses `tput(1)` to make the cursor visible again (`cnorm` or `cursor_normal` capability) before returning back to the shell.

As visible in the shell code above, this function uses a bit of the shell's [`trap`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/bash.1.en#trap) trickery to achieve the desired behavior, but it all works fine with no issues or side effects.  You can verify that no temporary `trap` leftovers are present by executing `trap -p` before and after this function is executed and interrupted by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.  This function depends on the `tput(1)` utility, which is usually part of the [`ncurses(3X)`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/ncurses.3x.en) package that isn't always installed, so the function doesn't get defined at all in case the `tput(1)` utility isn't present.

Of course, you can also define a `date` alias to customize the default output format for the `date` command, or you can modify the `clock()` function to additionally specify the format string for the `date` command.  For example, here's the definition of an alias that I use in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```bash
alias date="date '+%A  %B %-d, %Y  %H:%M:%S %Z (%:z)'"
```

---

Here's another version of the `clock()` function that avoids the use of a couple of [bashisms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bashism) present in the original version of the function, and instead uses more portable constructs as suggested in the comments below:

```bash
if command -v 'tput' > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        function clock() {
                trap 'tput cnorm; trap - INT ERR' ERR
                trap 'tput cnorm; trap - INT ERR; return' INT
                tput civis
                while :; do
                        printf 'cr\nel\n' | tput -S
                        printf '%s' "$(date) "
                        sleep 1
                done
        }
fi
```

However, as also discussed in the comments below, this more portable version of the function most probably still requires `bash(1)` because the required `ERR` trap seems not to be available in the POSIX `sh(1P)`.

---

Below are the improved versions of the `clock()` function, which no longer suffer from the occasional flickering of the displayed digital clock, and eliminate the occasional skipping of an elapsed second.

The flickering was pronounced especially on slower systems, such as ARM-based devices, loaded with other resource-hungry processes.  It was caused by clearing the line to its end (`el` or `clr_eol` capability) *before* updating its contents, which is actually completely redundant, because all we need is to clear the line to its end *after* updating its contents, to cover the cases in which the updated contents has fewer characters than the replaced contents.

Simply overwriting the contents, which in most cases actually isn't much different than the replaced contents, avoids the flickering, and the subsequent execution of `tput el` handles the clearing of the rest of the line.

These improved versions also eliminate the occasional (actually, pretty much periodic) skipping of displaying an elapsed second while the digital clock is updated.  Previously, using the fixed one-second update delay interval caused displaying an elapsed second to be skipped periodically because the delays created by executing various commands added up over time, causing the overall update delay to occasionally become longer than one second.

In addition to eliminating the skipped seconds, these improved versions also produce much more fluent updating of the digital clock, by performing the updates always around `ss.200000000`, on each elapsed second, where `200000000` is the nanosecond portion of the actual time.

Here's the improved fluent, flicker-free and skip-free version of the `clock()` function that uses some [bashisms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bashism):

```bash
if command -v 'tput' > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        function clock() {
                local LOOPDELAY
                trap 'tput cnorm; trap - INT ERR' ERR
                trap 'tput cnorm; trap - INT ERR; return' INT
                tput civis
                while :; do
                        tput cr
                        echo -n "$(date) "
                        tput el
                        LOOPDELAY=$(expr 1200000000 - $(command -p date '+%N'))
                        LOOPDELAY=$(expr ${LOOPDELAY} / 100000000)
                        sleep "$(expr ${LOOPDELAY} / 10).$(expr ${LOOPDELAY} % 10)"
                done
        }
fi
```

Here's also the improved fluent, flicker-free and skip-free version of the `clock()` function that uses fewer bashisms:

```bash
if command -v 'tput' > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        function clock() {
                local LOOPDELAY
                trap 'tput cnorm; trap - INT ERR' ERR
                trap 'tput cnorm; trap - INT ERR; return' INT
                tput civis
                while :; do
                        tput cr
                        printf '%s' "$(date) "
                        tput el
                        LOOPDELAY=$(expr 1200000000 - $(command -p date '+%N'))
                        LOOPDELAY=$(expr ${LOOPDELAY} / 100000000)
                        sleep "$(expr ${LOOPDELAY} / 10).$(expr ${LOOPDELAY} % 10)"
                done
        }
fi
```

However, as discussed in the comments below, this more portable version of the function most probably still requires `bash(1)` because the required `ERR` trap seems not to be available in the POSIX `sh(1P)`.

Obviously, the improved versions above rely on the [`sleep(1)`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/sleep.1.en) utility being capable of accepting fractional delay values, which most of its implementations and versions seem to support properly.

---

All versions of the `clock()` function have been updated to [`trap`](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) properly [`SIGINT`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/signal.7.en#Standard_signals) as well, and to clear this additional `trap` handler, which was required to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> keypresses properly in all cases.

Comment: Putting  this in an alias is completely misdirected. Generally speaking, you should prefer functions over aliases, especially for anything nontrivial.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see why it doesn't fit well as an alias.  Yes, it does a lot for an alias, but not having functions is something that I prefer until really necessary.  I do use functions as well in my `~/.bashrc`, but only when they do much more and, as a result, require much more code.

Comment: Hmm, on second thought, I'll actually consider converting it to a function a bit later.

Comment: Got it converted to a function.  It's much more readable that way, and I agree that it fits better into a function.  Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Stylistically, I would prefer `printf` over the nonportable `echo` switches. They are always available in Bash, of course, but I see no reason to prefer them over the more portable, versatile, readable, and elegant solution.

Comment: Perhaps that can be left as an exercise for the people who use other shells.  Personally, I'm inclined toward simply using what `bash` provides, and I've always considered `printf` to be some kind of a "heavyweight" alternative to `echo`, which actually made me avoid using `printf` until really needed.  Maybe that's just a wrong assumption?

Comment: The main beneft in my book is that unlearning `echo -e` is overall an improvement in your own shell scripting vocabulary. Somehow `printf '%s' "$(date)"` (or, of course, `date | tr -d '\n'`) seems more transparent and less clunky, with the additional benefit that these will work where you need to write POSIX shell scripts.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification.  I'll think more about it, but please keep in mind that I'm simply used to some `bash`isms, so they actually make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @tripleee, please check the bashism-free version of the improved `clock()` function, to verify that it actually uses no bashisms.

Comment: The `ERR` trap is Bash only IIRC.

Comment: Perhaps more testing with other shells would be required, to see how to handle the traps properly for them.  It takes time to do that, though, just as detailed testing with `bash` took me a lot of time.

Comment: The simple but unattractive fix is to just take out that line, and live with the fact that there is no good portable way to recover from errors.

Comment: Quite frankly, I don't see that as a viable option.  Without the `ERR` trap in place, the whole thing wouldn't work like 95% of the time.  Portability is good, unless it makes the things not work, IMHO.

Comment: But then the conclusion is that you can't really solve this in POSIX `sh`, and probably want a solution in a different language. I happen to like Python, but what exactly will work for you depends on your requirements.

Comment: Well, *it works for me* in `bash`, which is one of the worst answers, I know.  However, I don't care that much for my solution requiring `bash`, simply because requiring Python or PHP would actually make the requirement footprint much larger.  I'll edit my answer to clearly indicate that it requires `bash` and I'll leave porting to other shells as an exercise for the readers.

Comment: (Obviously, choose a compiled language if you want a standalone solution. Porting this to Rust or Go would probably be an excellent way to start learning a new language. The main challenge seems to be which "curses" library to choose.)

Comment: `function` is a (heavy! And almost completely unnecessary) Bashism, too. `local` is not in POSIX either; but some `sh` implementations support it, and it's pretty good hygiene, so I would perhaps keep it.

Comment: On the other hand, you probably want to avoid `expr` in the Bash version, and perhaps even in the somewhat more portable version. POSIX, too, supports [arithmetic expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) for integer expressions.

Comment: Ah, my development version didn't use `expr`, and I actually had no intentions to use it, but the trouble is that `date '%N'` returns nanoseconds padded wirh leading zeros, which `bash` treats wrongly as octal numbers.  Thus, I opted for using `expr` as a more simple solution for that, i.e. rather than stripping the leading zeros in some rather convoluted shell code, and I continued using `expr` throughout for more consistent code.

Comment: If I wanted to take the compiled language route, I'd actually choose C, but such an approach wouldn't make much sense, quite frankly.  My intention is to have something that can be added to one's `~/.bashrc`, in form of a few lines of shell code, rather than having some compiled binary that may even need to be packaged separately, which differs completely for various Linux distibutions, or even for different operating systems, etc.  It's a mess I actually want to avoid and have a simple solution instead.

Comment: Also, it's a bit funny that the OP seemingly no longer cares about their question, while we're trying to produce a more portable version of the code that attempts to answer their question. :)